# Is there an alternative to Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

Tags: java, runtime.exec

Just wondering, if there is something better, newer, safer, faster, etc than `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`.

I want to run another process from my application on linux, and this is the only way i know how. Would be nice to have an alternative.

Comment: Is this way somehow (specifically) insufficient?  It sounds like you're just asking for duplicated functionality.

Comment: java.lang.Process isn't newer. For some purposes it might be better.

Comment: i am not saying there is anything wrong with getRuntime.exec its just that i learned about it many years ago in java 1.3, it's the only way i know how and was wondering if there is more than one way to skin a cat, thats all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)?

A bit more:

Introduced in Java 1.5, allows you to gain more control on the process environment - set the working directory, let you redirect the error stream to the input stream (from java POV) and a few more things.

From [Oracle's site](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/lang/enhancements.html):

> ProcessBuilder - The new ProcessBuilder class provides a more
>   convenient way to invoke subprocesses than does Runtime.exec. In
>   particular, ProcessBuilder makes it easy to start a subprocess with a
>   modified process environment (that is, one based on the parent's
>   process environment, but with a few changes).

Comment: ...raising my brow, scratching my chin in interest.

Comment: If I may ask...is there a way to execute commands from Java code without using ProcessBuilder and Runtime.getRuntime() API's?