# Is it possible to execute adb commands through my android app?

Tags: android, adb

Can anyone say, whether `adb` commands can be executed through my android application. If it is possible to execute, how it can be implemented?

Comment: did you find a way to run adb on the device? I only get the message: error: device not found when running adb direct on the device

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**You can do it with this:**

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your command");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```

Don't forget to surround it with a try and catch statement.

**Edit:**

@Phix is right, [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) would be better to use.

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime()` has been set aside.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069425/is-there-an-alternative-to-runtime-getruntime-exec

Comment: Will this be able to execute the adb commands even if the device is not connected via USB?

Comment: I'm trying to run "adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_BACK" but it doesn't work. Please can you help me?  Thank you

Comment: you can directly pass the keycode to command like :                               adb shell input keyevent 26 (power key)

Comment: this is working on emulator (geny motion) , but not on real device. what to do ?

Comment: ProcessBuilder proc = new ProcessBuilder("adb pull /storage/sdcard/s.txt C:/Users/401896/Desktop/adbPush.txt");
    Process p = proc.start();

I have tried this and its throwing error. Can any one help

Comment: This is not working for me, getting : Error running exec(). Command: [adb, shell, pm, clear, com.package.project

Any help?

Comment: @HeitorColangelo sorry man - been a while since I did that, don't really remember anything about it now :/

Comment: I am getting Cannot run program "": error=13, Permission denied :(

Comment: This is working on emulator but not working on real device. may be needed root devices.

Answer (score 15):

Normal Android apps have different privileges to processes started via `adb`, e.g., processes started via `adb` are allowed to the capture the screen whereas normal apps aren't. So, you can execute commands from your app via `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`, but they won't have the same privileges as if you had executed from an `adb shell`.

Comment: could you tell what different privileges you have? any source?

Comment: I have this problem @Anthea, so anecdotal?

Comment: Very simple, if Android allowed access to ADB as the `shell` user from any, random Android app it would be a big security flaw. The `shell` user has full access to the ADB features, it's meant for device debugging and can be acessed only from USB debugging.

Answer (score 5):

i came across this post looking for a different query, but i have worked specifically with `input` on android before, so I'd just like to put some clarity on the matter.

The reason why

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell input keyevent 120");
```

Is not working, is because you are not removing

```
adb shell
```

The `ADB` part is only for use on your computer, if you have incorrectly installed ADB, the command would actually be a path to the adb.exe file on your computer, like this

```
C:\XXXX\ADB Files\adb.exe shell
```

or
     C:\XXXX\ADB Files\adb shell

The `shell` part tells the ADB program on your computer to access the devices shell, so your device will not know what shell is either...

Using `sh /path/to/commandList.sh` will execute the commads listed in commandList.sh as it is a shell script (a .batch file on windows is similar )

The command you want to use is

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input keyevent 120");
```

However this will cause Environment null and working directory null, you can bypass this by writing the commands to a shell script ( .sh file ) and then running the script with

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh path/to/shellScript.sh");
```

Sometimes the `sh` is not needed, but i use it just incase.

I hope this clears at least something up :)

Comment: Hi, It runs without adb shell, but not all commands work. Simple commands like swipe, keyevent do not show any effect however they work with adb shell from a system. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do in Kotlin, I also get command responses too

```
fun runShellCommand(command: String) {
    // Run the command
    val process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)
    val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(
        InputStreamReader(process.inputStream)
    )

    // Grab the results
    val log = StringBuilder()
    var line: String?
    line = bufferedReader.readLine()
    while (line != null) {
        log.append(line + "\n")
        line = bufferedReader.readLine()
    }
    val Reader = BufferedReader(
        InputStreamReader(process.errorStream)
    )

    // if we had an error during ex we get here
    val error_log = StringBuilder()
    var error_line: String?
    error_line = Reader.readLine()
    while (error_line != null) {
        error_log.append(error_line + "\n")
        error_line = Reader.readLine()
    }
    if (error_log.toString() != "")
        Log.info("ADB_COMMAND", "command : $command $log error $error_log")
    else
        Log.info("ADB_COMMAND", "command : $command $log")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

adb shell invoked in Runtime.getRuntime().exec is not running under shell user. It provide shell but with same process owner user (like u0_a44). That's the reason all command did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Executing

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell input keyevent 120");
```

I got the following error: 
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "adb": error=13, Permission denied.

Executing

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell input keyevent 120");
```

There is no error but at the same time, my request is not processed to take the screenshot.

I found out this was working in earlier versions of android but later it was removed. Though I'm not able to provide the source here why it is not working.

Hope this helps someone like me who is trying to use this approach to take the screenshot when the app is not in the foreground.

Comment: If you want to use this tool do not forget to add permission into your android manifest automatically `android.permission.DUMP`

Answer (score 0):

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
string cmd = "/system/bin/input keyevent 23\n";
os.writeBytes(cmd);
```

the phone must be rooted. here I have executed adb command "input keyevent 23".
remember when you execute adb command through su you does not need to add "adb shell input keyevent 23"