# How to set screen off on a rooted android device?

Tags: android

I have a rooted android device . I wish to set display off on it at a scheduled time.

How can i set screen off programatically on that?
Can we do it using Linux commands?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use, `adb shell input keyevent`

Usage :

```
adb shell input keyevent [--longpress] <key code number or name>
```

To Turn your Screen off, use Keycode

```
26 -->  "KEYCODE_POWER"`
```

Run this from your prompt:

```
root@user:/$ adb shell input keyevent 26
```

Or this,

```
root@user:/$ adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_POWER
```

Run the above command from your Function/Method : 
[Execute ADB Command through Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381828/is-it-possible-to-execute-adb-commands-through-my-android-app).

This procedure works for a Non-rooted device too.

Complete List of Events : [See Here](http://codeforfun.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/android-device-automation-with-adb/)
Setting up ADB : [See Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/)

Comment: I am saying programatically that is ..from inside an app.

Comment: Have you tried here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381828/is-it-possible-to-execute-adb-commands-through-my-android-app

Comment: Is there a way to turn off screen withtout root, and without locking the device?

Answer (score 0):

For those with the same issue like me: I found on my MTK device following code to turn off the screen, because `keyevent 26` doesn't work on my device:

> adb shell input keyevent 6

will turn off the devices screen also. To turn on the devices screen, you can do it with `keyevent 26`.

The best way to find out which keyevent works for your device is with a tiny bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while
do
    count=$(( $count+1 ))
    input keyevent $count
    echo "input keyevent $count"
    sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sleeping="$(adb shell dumpsys power | grep 'mWakefulness=')"
screen="$(adb shell dumpsys nfc| grep 'mScreenState=')"

case "$screen" in
  "mScreenState=OFF")
     echo "* Device is not unlocked."
                 ;;
  "mScreenState=ON_LOCKED")
     echo "* Device is not unlocked."
     sleep 0
     exit ;;
   "mScreenState=ON_UNLOCKED")
       echo "* Locking screen.."
       adb shell input keyevent 26
       echo "* Screen turned off"
       exit
esac

echo -e "$basename$0: internal error -- can't lock screen since it's not unlocked"
```