# Executing shell command on Android

Tags: android, cordova, terminal

I'm wondering if Cordova or any plugin for Cordova enables me to execute a command in the android shell? Similar to doing `adb shell myCoolBinary -doThisStuff` on a desktop machine connected to the phone.

Googling for this only returns tutorials for how to use the Cordova cli desktop application, which absolutely NOT what I'm looking for. I want to execute commands ON the phone.

Comment: maybe you have to create a plugin for this ( check [native example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13381888/3419997) )

Comment: That would be unfortunate, I've never written a single line of Java so far. Let alone native Android apps.

Comment: You ever get a solution or answer for this?

Comment: Well you have to write you own addon. I'll post an answer with a quick dirty addon that I used to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing my own plugin.
I mostly put it together from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26654728/1382768) that was about doing root shell executes from within your android app. I just adapted it to cordova.

I don't have the time to make this nice so here is a gist:
https://gist.github.com/PTS93/d78ee885ee0c2f74892434008a953f8c

Just replace the files with the files from this plugin template:
https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-hello

You can then in your cordova app call this:

```
shell.execute("your shell command", success, failure);
```

Comment: this use only root