# Pass commands to adb through android app

Tags: java, android, adb

I am looking for a way to run a command located in a text file inside of an android app using the adb. Is this possible? I know it possible to read a file through the adb, but is it possible to run a files contents ('adb shell '...)  without viewing it's contents?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this: [Is it possible to execute adb commands through my android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381828/is-it-possible-to-execute-adb-commands-through-my-android-app)

BUT you might get an `android.permission.SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER` lack of permission exception or another, which are for internal use only. More of them are listed [HERE](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/OvCcdvO6jZY)