# How can i run my adb command through apk

Tags: android

My ADB command is,

```
adb shell am instrument -w -r -e debug false -e class com.example.deepak.myapplication.ExampleInstrumentedTest com.example.deepak.myapplication.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to execute adb commands through my android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381828/is-it-possible-to-execute-adb-commands-through-my-android-app)

Comment: This command is not working when try to run instrument command.

Comment: This command is of uiautomator actually so this question is not duplicate.