# Get internal file android

Tags: android, shell

I have a java file that have this piece of code to list the files in the cache directory of an app and it works well.

```
 String command[] = {"adb","shell","run-as",pack,"ls","cache/"};
 Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
 InputStream o_out = process.getInputStream(); //covert o_out to String to get the files name
```

Now i want to this code to run on directly on android devices, but it fails because the command was wrong, any idea?

Comment: What is the exect command that you are using? What is the response or the error?

Comment: please explain, why it is required to use shell command in the given situation. this would be possibly be a `java` question then, but not exactly an `android` question.

Comment: Maybe this is a part of your problem solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22985070

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
String command[] = {"run-as",pack,"ls","cache/"};
```

Comment: Still not work, but thanks anw, i think i can get the internal file within the app without using process.

Comment: "Try this" aka random guess answers are not useful because they don't show why this should work and how it should be adapted if it doesn't work (as in your case). Please consider adding some explanation text.