# How to have an APK uninstall an android package

Tags: android, apk

I want to make an APK that will uninstall a certain android package when installed on a phone? I know how to do this with ADB, but I don't know how to put this into a compiled APK. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to execute adb commands through my android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381828/is-it-possible-to-execute-adb-commands-through-my-android-app)

Comment: @SrikarReddy That looks more like how to run the command, but I want to have a compiled apk that can uninstall an android package.

Comment: Try running the uninstall adb command `pm uninstall -k --user 0 NameOfPackage` to uninstall android packages using the above approach. Won't that suffice your use case?

Comment: Running or Executing commands as soon as the app is installed is not possible (at least for non-rooted devices.).

Comment: The applications will be in a stopped state and the Android system won't let any service of the app run unless the user first interacts with it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8535062

Comment: @SrikarReddy I am trying to figure out how to have an APK uninstall an android package when it is opened. Not with ADB, just the APK would be able to uninstall a package by itself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813322/install-uninstall-apks-programmatically-packagemanager-vs-intents

Comment: @SrikarReddy thanks